# Начиная с какой минимальной версии Android можно загружать приложения в google play market?

Tags: java, android, мобильная-разработка, мобильные-приложения

Недавно слышал, что для того, чтобы загрузить приложение в google play market, минимальная версия для него должна быть не ниже android 8.0. Это так или нет?
И если нет, то начиная с какой версии можно его загружать приложения?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Минимальная версия (`minSdkVersion`) может быть любой, а вот целевая (`targetSdkVersion`):

**Android 8.0 (API уровня 26)**

- С 1 августа 2018 года требуется для новых приложений.
- С 1 ноября 2018 года требуется для обновлений приложений.

**Android 9 (API уровня 28)**

- С 1 августа 2019 года будет требоваться для новых приложений.
- С 1 ноября 2019 года будет требоваться для обновлений приложений.

**Android 10 (API уровня 29)***

- С 3 августа 2020 года потребуется для новых приложений.
- Со 2 ноября 2020 года потребуется для обновлений приложений.

*Требование об API уровня 29 не относится к приложениям для Wear OS.

Как только эти требования вступят в силу, в Play Console нельзя будет загрузить новые APK-файлы с более ранними целевыми уровнями API.

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/113469#targetsdk

Answer (score 2):

Минимальную поддерживаемую версию (minSdkVersion) можно ставить любую, но ниже 16 sdk просто нет смысла. Ограничения вводятся на targetSdkVersion. Сейчас нельзя опубликовать или обновить приложение с target sdk ниже 26 (android 8.0), с первого ноября 2019г. под запрет попадут версии ниже 28 (android 9.0).

Это связано с безопасностью. Например после добавления runtime permissions в 23 sdk, долгое время можно было публиковать приложения таргетированные под старые версии, не заморачиваясь с новым api, они получали все разрешения при установке на девайс, по старинке.

Answer (score 0):

В принципе, можно использовать любую версию `targetSdkVersion`, в том числе несуществующую: внутри манифеста (уже скомпилированного приложения) можно просто запатчить это значение. И вы знаете, это вполне работает!

Если попробовать декомпилировать такое приложение, то видно внутри следующее:

```
<manifest versionCode="1" versionName="1.0" compileSdkVersion="28" compileSdkVersionCodename="9" package="******" platformBuildVersionCode="28" platformBuildVersionName="9">

    <uses-sdk minSdkVersion="3" targetSdkVersion="85">
```

Как вы видите, я являюсь элитарным ведроразработчиком, так как могу компилять свои приложения с 85-й версией SDK!

Чего я не ожидал, так это то, что в файл добавляются поля о реальной версии SDK: compileSdkVersion="28" compileSdkVersionCodename="9"  platformBuildVersionCode="28" platformBuildVersionName="9" - в оригинальном файле, который проходит компиляцию, этих полей НЕТУ, потому немного палевно.

Готовых тулзов для такого извращения не знаю, но если надо быстро сделать "обновление", а исходники не собираются, то вполне можно заморочиться с хекс-редактором. Конечно, можно запатчить еще и minSdkVersion, но надо понимать, что если рантайм наткнется на вызов, которого не понимает, то будет все плохо. Еще надо помнить, что после патча, система начинает думать, что вы реально смогли такое скомпилять и может применять повышенные требования безопасности, так что выдать все пермишшены таким образом не выйдет. А вот завышать версию targetSdkVersion можно до небес.

Comment: Вопрос-то был не о том, чтобы скомпилировать, а о том чтобы опубликовать в маркете. Мы можем много чего понаделать, что система на устройстве примет нашу поделку, но допустят ли такое к публикации?...